# Does Dalvik VM talk to HAL/kernel layer via Bionic Libc?

Tags: android, android-ndk, hal

In the given android stack,

## [image]

excluding applications written using NDK kit at LIBRARIES layer,
I learnt that, Any app written at APPLICATIONS layer must run in their own processes, inside their own Dalvik VM instance, as shown below:

[image]

As per the process stack above, I see that Dalvik runtime is talking to HAL/kernel layer via `bionic` Libc library.

My question:

Can't Dalvik VM access HAL/Kernel layer without using `bionic` Libc library interface?

Comment: Not sure if you have seen this 2008 Google IO talk: https://sites.google.com/site/io/anatomy--physiology-of-an-android

Comment: The VM doesn't really need to do anything that isn't provided by libc.  It does have access to some functions that weren't necessarily made public in the NDK (e.g. ashmem helpers).

Comment: @fadden Can't this question be answered as yes or no? and then why?

Answer (score 0):

i see some confusion in you when it comes to C Language.

after all bionic is just standard C library for android.

first of all, your answer is NO.
although bionic libC is not below Dalvik in their diagram, the fact is that Dalvik uses libC helper functions to perform some tasks that are considered as operating system services.
like:

> string handling, mathematical computations, input/output processing, ***memory allocation*** and several other operating system services.